# In Drupal 7, I am trying to rewrite the Bulk Media Upload module to remove the .jpg extension from the Node Title

Tags: php

I am not very good at writing PHP, but I would like to write something in the Bulk Media Upload that strips out the .jpg that is being generated in the Node Title.  We are uploading hundreds of images like 1234.jpg with drag a drop in Bulk Media Upload for a user who does not know how to use Excel or FTP.  It works great for her, but the Node Title cannot have the .jpg extension in order for people to search and find their certificate by 1234.

Thanks in advance.

Tried adding a line recommended to remove .mp3

```
//Attempting to Remove the .mp3 or simply the file extension 
$label = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '',$label);
```

But it did not remove the file extension.

Here is the area around the place where the original author recommended adding the above:

```
// Additional values for filefield (and imagefield).
if(in_array($fieldinfo['module'], $filefields)){
$settings['display'] = 1;
$settings['description'] = '';
 };

 $entity->$mediafield_name = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => $settings));

// Default values.
if (isset($form['default_values'])) {
field_attach_submit($entity_type, $entity, $form['default_values'], $form_state);
}

 entity_save($entity_type, $entity);

// Replace tokens in title - this has to be done after entity_save.
$label = token_replace($form_state['values']['title'], array($entity_type => $entity,      'file' => $file), array('clear' => TRUE));

$entity->$label_field = $label;

 //Attempting to Remove the .mp3 or simply the file extension 
$label = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '',$label);

entity_save($entity_type, $entity);

$context['message'] = t('Importing: @filename', array('@filename' => $file->filename));
$context['results']['ids'][] = $entity->$entity_info['entity keys']['id'];
}
```

All I want to do is strip out the .jpg from the Node Title, but I need some friendly help.

Comment: Maybe you just need to do `$entity->$label_field = $label;` _after_ you modified what `$label` contains?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I've since written a sql script to strip out the .jpg from titles on a schedule.